# How to show that ${(\ln n)}^{\ln n}=n^{\ln(\ln n)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How to show that $${(\ln n)}^{\ln n}=n^{\ln(\ln n)}$$

Attempt:

$y={(\ln n)}^{\ln n}$ then $\ln y=\ln n\ln(\ln n)$ what to do next?

Comment: If $\ln y=\ln n\ln(\ln n)$, $y=e^{\log(y)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We have

$${(\ln n)}^{\ln n}=e^{\ln n\cdot \ln (\ln n)}=(e^{\ln n})^{\ln (\ln n)}$$

and recall that by definition $e^{\ln n}=n$.

Comment: Understand. But please write the next line

Comment: @user1942348 simly note that $e^{\ln n}=n$

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Take log on both sides

> $${(\ln n)}^{\ln n}=n^{\ln(\ln n)}$$
>   Taking log gives 
>   $$ \ln\left({(\ln n)}^{\ln n}\right) =\ln\left(n^{\ln(\ln n)}\right)$$
>   $$ \ln({n})( \ln(\ln(n))= {\ln(\ln n)} \ln(n)$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:
$${(\color{red}{\ln n})}^{\color{blue}{\ln n}}=(\color{red}{e^{\ln (\ln n)}})^{\color{blue}{\ln n}}=(e^{\color{blue}{\ln n}})^{\color{red}{\ln (\ln n)}}=n^{\ln(\ln n)}$$